# Target Specific Elements Within an Array

Tags: php, css, arrays, smarty

I'm trying to apply styling to each word in my php array. I can't figure out how to target each individual word.

My site lists a ton of demographics as tags about the user. Example:

```
Hometown: LA
Date of Birth: 1985
Majors: Political Science, Math

Interests: Ice hockey, soccer, art, music,
running, bodybuilding, writing, cooking,
fashion, videos

Skills: Reading, writing, driving, boxing
```

The first 3 categories are easy to style in HTML/CSS because there is only one element. For example, we do not allow for the user to have two hometowns. A user cannot have two birtdates. So I can do anything to these tags. I can make them huge, i can turn them into a box, I can add a HR line between each..

But then when I go to style majors, interests, and skills I run into a huge problem.

Let's say for example I want to turn the interests from the above example to this:

```
Hockey
Soccer
Art 
Music
etc..
```

and further style each tag within the array with maybe a blue bg then how can I do this?

Here is the example php code for interests:

```
$interests = str_replace("\"","",explode(',',$usrNfo['interests']));
$interests = implode(", ",$interests);

//interests -> a
$interests2 = str_replace("\"","",explode(',',$usrNfo['interests']));

foreach($interests2 as $a => &$b)
{
    $bs = str_replace(" ","+",$b);
    $b = "<a class=\"various fancybox.ajax\"  href='".$config['url']['site']."rpc/tag.php?type=interests&school=$usrNfo[school]&int=$bs'>$b</a>";
}

$interests = implode(", ",$interests2);

$usrNfo['interests_text'] = $interests;
```

then it's outputted in the TPL file as

```
<div class="rig">
    <div class="sin">
        <b>Interests:</b>  {$user.interests_text} 
    </div>
    <div class="sin">
        <b>Skills:</b> {$user.skills_text}
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I target each tag within the array?

Comment: You could, instead of imploding in your PHP code, just use a Smarty {section} tag. See: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section Then you could just add the styling inside the TPL file.